# Complex analysis question involving Cauchy–Riemann theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

So I have to find if $w=ln|z|$ is an analytical function or not.Which means that I have to prove this using Cauchy–Riemann theorem.
So $w=ln|x+i*y|$ and now comes the interesting part.

How do I find  $∂u/ ∂x$= ? 
EDIT : I know how to find partial derivatives but how about this one?

Comment: Hint: what is $|x+iy|$?

Comment: ah I got this.Thank you. |x+iy|= sqrt(x+iy)^2

Comment: Not quite but close: $|x+iy| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Comment: yes thats what i meant!thanks again.

Comment: Note that CR equations are neccessary but not sufficient.

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai Why ? :)

Comment: The partial derivatives have to exist and be continuous throughout the domain .